# Class 'Input' not found

Tags: search, laravel-5, search-engine

I am trying to implement smart search engine for my Laravel 5.2 app.
Here is the tutorial of Laravel 4 and I want to implement in Laravel 5:

https://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/laravel-shop-tutorial-3-implementing-smart-search/

but I am stuck in ApiSearchController and I am getting:

```
Class 'Input' not found
```

Here is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Input;
use App\Http\Requests;

class ApiSearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $query = e(Input::get('q',''));

        if(!$query && $query == '') return Response::json(array(), 400);

        $products = Product::where('published', true)
            ->where('name','like','%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('name','asc')
            ->take(5)
            ->get(array('slug','name','icon'))->toArray();

        $categories = Category::where('name','like','%'.$query.'%')
            ->has('products')
            ->take(5)
            ->get(array('slug', 'name'))
            ->toArray();

        // Data normalization
        $categories = $this->appendValue($categories, url('img/icons/category-icon.png'),'icon');

        $products   = $this->appendURL($products, 'products');
        $categories  = $this->appendURL($categories, 'categories');

        // Add type of data to each item of each set of results
        $products = $this->appendValue($products, 'product', 'class');
        $categories = $this->appendValue($categories, 'category', 'class');

        // Merge all data into one array
        $data = array_merge($products, $categories);

        return Response::json(array(
            'data'=>$data
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I Found Sollution
This i use and success

```
in config.php
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

and

```
in Controller
use Input;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `aliases` in `config/app.php` add line to `aliases`

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```